# How to calculate years and months between two dates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to calculate the count of years (considering leap years also) and months between two different dates in Javascript?

Comment: When you say years,month, do you mean years and months?

Comment: yeah of course , i was able to calculate the years but not able to get the month difference

Comment: hi skilldrick i found following  to be a useful in getting months
http://wordsanddeeds.org/blog/2007/04/javascript-get-number-of-months-between-two-dates-34

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You will find a complete [javascript function](http://javascript.internet.com/math-related/date-difference.html) here with validation.

Edit: Link is dead - here is a simple JS line that calculates the difference in months between two dates:

```
return dateTo.getMonth() - dateFrom.getMonth() + 
       (12 * (dateTo.getFullYear() - dateFrom.getFullYear()));
```

That is assuming that you have the dates in two variables called `dateTo` and `dateFrom`.

Comment: hi fabian ,thats was useful piece ,but it doesn't helps me in getting month.

Comment: hi i found this to be useful for getting months

http://wordsanddeeds.org/blog/2007/04/javascript-get-number-of-months-between-two-dates-34

Comment: Updated the question and added code. Guess I should've done this in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the best way I know to get years and months:

```
// Assumes Date From (df) and Date To (dt) are valid etc...
var df= new Date("01/15/2010");
var dt = new Date("02/01/2012");   
var allMonths= dt.getMonth() - df.getMonth() + (12 * (dt.getFullYear() - df.getFullYear()));
var allYears= dt.getFullYear() - df.getFullYear();
var partialMonths = dt.getMonth() - df.getMonth();
if (partialMonths < 0) {
    allYears--;
    partialMonths = partialMonths + 12;
}
var total = allYears + " years and " + partialMonths + " months between the dates.";
var totalMonths = "A total of " + allMonths + " between the dates.";
console.log(total);
console.log(totalMonths);  


return {jaren: allYears, maanden: partialMonths};
```

Comment: I would like to contribute:     `code`function stringToDate(_date,_format,_delimiter){
    var formatLowerCase=_format.toLowerCase();
    var formatItems=formatLowerCase.split(_delimiter);
    var dateItems=_date.split(_delimiter);
    var monthIndex=formatItems.indexOf("mm");
    var dayIndex=formatItems.indexOf("dd");
    var yearIndex=formatItems.indexOf("yyyy");
    var month=parseInt(dateItems[monthIndex]);
    month-=1;
    var formatedDate = new Date(dateItems[yearIndex],month,dateItems[dayIndex]);
    return formatedDate;
}

Answer (score 1):

This might be a helpful source:

http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-date1.htm#DYMD

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet contains my solution. It's based on the idea that a currentDate - pastDate already is the result.

If you don't want negative results, you have to check that years and month is not less than 0.

```js
const pastDate = '1989-02-10'

const period = new Date(new Date().getTime() - new Date(pastDate).getTime())
const years = period.getFullYear() - 1970 // at 1970 the date calendar starts
const months = period.getMonth()

console.log('years: ', years, ', month: ', months)
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the [JavaScript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp).