# AngularJs:Getting age automatically when given Date of Birth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have a date of birth field and a age text box.How can i update age text box automatically when selecting date of birth in angularJs.
code for inputs

```
 <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label">Dob</label>
  <input type="datepicker"class="form-control" my-date-picker required="required" ng-model="newItem.dob" />
  <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label">Age</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  disabled="true"  ng-model="newItem.age"  />
```

Comment: Can you please post the coe you've already tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the number of years betwen two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-betwen-two-dates)

Comment: @MikeRobinson .i need solution in angularjs

Comment: @NishamMahsin you can use `$watch`. Just watch for the changes made to `dob` and update `age` in the callback.

Comment: You should at least attempt a solution, demonstrate you've read the help docs and post some sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, add ng-change to your first input, call a function when a input change is made. The function must be declared in the scope.

```
<label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label">Dob</label>
<input type="datepicker" ng-change='myAgeFunction()' class="form-control" my-date-picker required="required" ng-model="newItem.dob" />
<label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label">Age</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  disabled="true"  ng-model="newItem.age"  />
```

Javascript in your controller:

```
$scope.newItem = {dob: "00/00/0000", age: 0 } // your object which refers to ng-model
$scope.myAgeFunction = function(){ //your function goes here
    $scope.newItem.age = ... code to calculate age; // update the model
}
```