# How to automatic populate age field after filling up birthdate with a format of YYYY-MM-DD using JS

Tags: javascript

Please help. I tried this code but I wasn't able to change it's format. I need the date to accept the format YYYY/MM/DD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ageCount() {
        var date1 = new Date();
        var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
        var date2 = new Date(dob);
        var pattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
        //Regex to validate date format (dd/mm/yyyy)       
        if (pattern.test(dob)) {
            var y1 = date1.getFullYear();
            //getting current year            
            var y2 = date2.getFullYear();
            //getting dob year            
            var age = y1 - y2;
            //calculating age                       
            document.getElementById("ageId").value = age;
            doucment.getElementById("ageId").focus();
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Invalid date format. Please Input in (dd/mm/yyyy) format!");
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-betwen-two-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the regex from

```
var pattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
```

to

```
var pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;
```

And it should do.

Check Here : http://jsfiddle.net/fP875/

***WARNING***

But remember the regex you are using is not exactly correct. You'll need a more precise regex to check date.

Your regex will accept dates like 2014-23-56 or 9999-99-99.

I'll recommend this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18759740/3603806
if you need accurate dates and not just formatting.

http://jsfiddle.net/EywSP/856/

http://jsfiddle.net/EywSP/854/

Answer (score 0):

just take this
[javascript date manipulation library [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802861/javascript-date-manipulation-library)

> I wrote a javascript date library called moment.js
>
> https://github.com/moment/moment
>
> It creates date wrapper objects so that it doesn't have to modify
>   Date.prototype.
>
> It includes parsing from strings, date objects, and unix timestamps.
>
> It can format based on replacement patterns ("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY,
>   h:mm:ss a") and also includes time ago ("2 days ago", 6 months ago")