# How to get months and years from deadline date

Tags: jquery

How to get months and years from deadline date.

```
var deadline = '12 28 2016 18:40:18 GMT-0400';
var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());

var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
var months = // ?
var years = // ?
```

Comment: i want also divide t variable so get it correct all second minutes and hour....

Answer (score 0):

LMGTFY:

```
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

```
function yearDiff(d1, d2) { // birthday is a date
    var yearDiffMs = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    var yearDate = new Date(yearDiffMs);
    return Math.abs(yearDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-betwen-two-dates)

EDIT: If you want everything separately, here's a nice way:

```
// Make sure both are valid date objects
var diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2);

var year = myDate.getFullYear();
var month = (myDate.getMonth() + 1);
var dateOfDay = myDate.getDate();

var hours = myDate.getHours();
var minutes = myDate.getMinutes();
var seconds = myDate.getSeconds();
var ms = myDate.getMilliseconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

First assign the date as a variable Date, like given below:

```
var deadline = new Date("December 28, 2016 06:00:00");

//to get date
var theDate = deadline.getDate()
//to get month
var theMonth = deadline.getMonth()
//to get month
var theMonth = deadline.getFullYear()
```

If your code is javascript to show your result

```
//to show date    
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = theDate;
//to show Month    
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = theMonth;
//to show date    
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = theYear;
```

If it is JQuery, print it like this

```
$("#showDate").html("theDate");
$("#showMonth").html("theMonth");
$("#showYear").html("theYear");
```

I hope this could help you!