# PHP JAVASCRIPT get years difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have source code `php` form there's a `inputtext about date (YYYY/mm/dd)` and i want to automate calculate the `diff between` input date and i want use `javascript(jquery)` after i finish input the diff date show ... years in textbox it's my code:

**date.php**

```
<form action="url.php" method="post">
    .........
    <input type:"text" name="date" id="date"/>
    .........
    <input type:"text" name="dur" id="dur" disabled="disable"/>
</form>
```

**my javascript**

```
function calc(){
   var now = new Date();
   var month = ("0"+(now.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
   var month = ("0"+now.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var year = now.getFullYear();
   var date = month+" / "+day+" / "+year;
   var date_form = $('#date').val();

   $('#dur').val(date - date_form);
}
```

and when i run the value of *dur* its show *NaN*

Comment: the php tag is irrelevant though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to pass the dates on change event of your input box and you will get the difference of year between two dates.

```js
function getYearDiff(startDate, endDate) {
    let yearDiff = endDate.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear();
    if (startDate.getMonth() > endDate.getMonth()) {
        yearDiff--;
    } else if (startDate.getMonth() === endDate.getMonth()) {
        if (startDate.getDate() > endDate.getDate()) {
            yearDiff--;
        } else if (startDate.getDate() === endDate.getDate()) {
            if (startDate.getHours() > endDate.getHours()) {
                yearDiff--;
            } else if (startDate.getHours() === endDate.getHours()) {
                if (startDate.getMinutes() > endDate.getMinutes()) {
                    yearDiff--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return yearDiff;
}

alert(getYearDiff(firstDate, secondDate));
```

Ref: [How can I calculate the number of years betwen two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-betwen-two-dates)

Comment: Please [don't plagiarise the work of others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45801004/519413). If you believe the question already has an answer elsewhere, vote to close it as such.

Comment: Ok sir, thank you.