# Filter array of users with age unrder 30 and sort it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I just start to learn JS. So, I need your help. How can I use `Array.sort()` with my code?

I have an array:

```
var users = [{
      first_name: "Brithany",
      last_name: "Allison",
      birthday: "1993-11-13",
  },
  {
      first_name: "Sonya",
      last_name: "Slowers",
      birthday: "1967-02-21",
  },
  {
      first_name: "Ashley",
      last_name: "Pratt",
      birthday: "1987-11-10",
  }
];
```

I need to receive all users under 30. 
  I can sort by birthday, but I don't understand how to receive users under 30 years

There is my code:

```
users.sort(function(a, b){
    var dateA=new Date(a.birthday), dateB=new Date(b.birthday)
    return dateA-dateB 
})
```

Comment: try to get their age then you sort Arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Array `filter` method and filter out anyone who is greater than 30 years old. The following code should get you there.

Note that `getTime` returns the time since January 1, 1970 in milliseconds.

```js
var users = [{
      first_name: "Brithany",
      last_name: "Allison",
      birthday: "1993-11-13",
  },
  {
      first_name: "Sonya",
      last_name: "Slowers",
      birthday: "1967-02-21",
  },
  {
      first_name: "Ashley",
      last_name: "Pratt",
      birthday: "1987-11-10",
  }
];

const under30 = users.filter(user => {
  const ageInSeconds = new Date().getTime() - new Date(user.birthday).getTime();
  return ageInSeconds < 30 * 365 * 86400 * 1000;
})

console.log(under30);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps what you need to do to achieve the goal:

1. Calculate the day when you have the limit for under 30 years, the function named `getBirthdayLimit` will do the job for this purpose.
2. Then applying a simple `filter` will help you to return only the users who are in the condition of `new Date(user.birthday) > birthdayLimit`.

So I would do the following:

```js
const users = [
  {
    first_name: "Brithany",
    last_name: "Allison",
    birthday: "1993-11-13",
  },
  {
    first_name: "Sonya",
    last_name: "Slowers",
    birthday: "1967-02-21",
  },
  {
    first_name: "Ashley",
    last_name: "Pratt",
    birthday: "1987-11-10",
  }
];

const getBirthdayLimit = () => {
  const d = new Date();
  const year = d.getFullYear();
  const month = d.getMonth();
  const day = d.getDate();
  return new Date(year - 30, month, day);
};

const birthdayLimit = getBirthdayLimit();
console.log('The birthday limit', birthdayLimit);

const under30 = users.filter((user) => (new Date(user.birthday) > birthdayLimit));

console.log(under30);
```

For [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the documentation states:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So, Sort will sort your objects, and the syntax looks good. Now, if you want to conditionally leave some objects in the array, you need .filter() method.

Example:

```
var usersBelowThirty = users.filter(u => new Date(u.birthday) < new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 30)))
```

This is a one liner, if you want to be elegant, i would assign two variables in the linq block and do the following:

```
var userBday = new Date(u.birthday);
var thirtyYearsAgo = new Date().setYear(new Date().getYear() - 30);
return userBday < thirtyYearsAgo;
```

Good luck with future endevours and welcome to the Programming world ;)

Comment: In addition to this, I would suggest using filter first then sort, less iterations in that case

Answer (score 0):

You should conceptually narrow down by following steps:

1. add the **calculated age** to each user-object using *map* function (incl. birthday-to-age function)
2. filter on **age less than 30**
3. sort by **age descending** (incl. comparator-function)

These 3 steps and 2 helper-functions are implemented as follows:

```
// helper function to get current age from birthday specified as Date object
function calculateAge(birthday) { // birthday is a date
   var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
   var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
   return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
};

// step 1: add age to each user 
var usersWithAge = users.map(function (user) { 
  user.age = calculateAge(new Date(user.birthday));
  return user;
});

// step 2: filter users where age < 30
var usersLessThanAge30 = usersWithAge.filter( function(user) {
  return user.age < 30;
});

// helper function (called comparator) to compare users' age 
function compareOnAgeDescending(a,b) {
  if (a.age < b.age
    return -1;
  if (a.age > b.age)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

// step 3: sort all users under 30 by age (descending: oldest to youngest)
var sortedForOlderstToYoungest = usersLessThanAge30.sort(compareOnAgeDescending);

// print results to console
console.log("users under 30 (oldest to youngest): ", sortedForOlderstToYoungest);
```

See following posts which covers the missing functions / steps for your solution

- answer to question [calculating age from birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24181701/5730279)
- well explained article on [array-functions map, filter](https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/javascripts-map-reduce-and-filter)
- sorting an array of objects [using a comparator function to Arrays.sort()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/5730279)