# How to take the differences between two dates, depending on the date of birth

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date

**My code:**

```
        function test(val) {
            year = parseInt(val.slice(0,2)); // get year
            month = parseInt(val.slice(2,4)); // get month
            date = val.slice(4,6); // get date

            if (month > 40) { // For people born after 2000, 40 is added to the month. (it is specific for my case)
                year += 2000;
                month -= 40;
            } else {
                year += 1900;
            }

            date = new Date(year, month-1, date, 0, 0);
            date_now = new Date();

            var diff =(date_now.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000;
            diff /= (60 * 60 * 24);
            console.log(Math.abs(Math.round(diff/365.25)));
        }
```

**Example 1**:

If I was born in

```
1993-year;
04-month(april); 
26-date
```

I will pass `930426` as value to test function and the **result would be 27 which is correct**

But in **Example 2**:

If I was born in:

```
1993-year;
09-month(september); 
14-date;
```

I will pass `930914` as value to test function and result would be 27, but it's not correct because my birthday is still not come and i'm still 26 years old.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I calculate the number of years between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-between-two-dates)

Comment: I do not want to use moment.js

Answer (score 1):

Because `26.9` is still regarded as age of `26`, so you should use `.floor` instead

```js
function test(val) {
  year = +val.slice(0, 2) // get year
  month = val.slice(2, 4) // get month
  date = val.slice(4, 6) // get date

  date = new Date(year, month - 1, date, 0, 0)
  date_now = new Date()

  var diff = (date_now.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000
  diff /= 60 * 60 * 24
  console.log(diff / 365.25)
  console.log("Age", Math.floor(diff / 365.25))
}

test("930426")
test("930914")
```

Comment: I thought that it works fine, but if you check with `test("940911")` and
`test("940909")` It returns 26 for both, which is not correct.