# JavaScript Date Of Birth Checker Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

Doesn't work correctly; always outputs "above 16". I have been tweeking the if statement but couldn't figure it out. Need some help, Thanks!

```js
function hasDateCheck() {
  let dateSpliter = document.querySelector("#dateOfBirth").value.split("-");
  console.log(`${dateSpliter[0]} ${dateSpliter[1]} ${dateSpliter[2]}`); // YYYY MM DD

  let today = new Date();
  let dd = today.getDate();
  let mm = today.getMonth();
  mm++;
  let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (yyyy - dateSpliter[0] < 16 && mm - dateSpliter[1] < 0 && dd - dateSpliter[2] < 0) {
    console.log("below 16");
  } else {
    console.log("above 16");
  }
}

document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  hasDateCheck();
});
```

```html
<input name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth" type="date" required/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" id="formSubmit">
```

Comment: I entered 10/20/2020 and it said below 16.

Comment: Why are you comparing the month and day? If the birth year is less than 16 years ago, why do the month and day matter?

Comment: I also checked with 16/05/2017 and it said `below 16`.

Comment: You only need to check the month if the birth year is exactly 16 years ago. And you only need to check the day if it's in the current month.

Comment: use `moment.js` library and the `diff` method, it'll make things easier.

Comment: Why do you keep adding a link to the fiddle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I calculate the number of years between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-between-two-dates)

Comment: if we enter 2005-02-12, it shows above 16

Comment: sorry, I was making it easier for you guys.

Comment: Right, it always says above 16 if the month is less than or equal to today's month, or the day is less than or equal to today's day.

Comment: As I said above, you shouldn't compare the month and day except when the year is exactly 16 years ago.

Comment: Did I do the if statement correctly?

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar, the idea helped me fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (yyyy - dateSpliter[0] > 16) {
        console.log("above 16");
    } else if (
        yyyy - dateSpliter[0] == 16 &&
        mm - dateSpliter[1] >= 0 &&
        dd - dateSpliter[2] >= 0) 
    {
        console.log("above 16");
    } else {
        guardianDetailsCheck();
        console.log("below 16");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your if condition is invalid,

replace your if condition with this,

```
if (yyyy - dateSpliter[0] <= 16 && mm - dateSpliter[1] <= 0 && dd - dateSpliter[2] <= 0) {
   console.log("below 16");
} else {
   console.log("above 16");
}
```

if you want to calculate age, then refer @Aniket answer

Comment: That's still wrong. You shouldn't compare the month and day unless the year is exactly 16 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to calculate age.

```
function age(birthday)
{
  birthday = new Date(birthday);
  return new Number((new Date().getTime() - birthday.getTime()) / 31536000000).toFixed(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `momentjs` if you can import a package

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'years')
```

[momentjs docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is incorrect, because, if today's date was January 15th, 2021, and you entered January 1st, 2000, it would reject it, because the *day* is smaller, even though the *year* is greater by more than 16.

The easiest way (with the less caveats) it to convert it to a Unix timestamp (a number representing the milliseconds passed since January 1th, 1970), and compare that way:

```js
function hasDateCheck() {
  const [YYYY, MM, DD] = document.querySelector("#dateOfBirth").value.split("-");
  const birthDate = new Date(+YYYY, +MM - 1, +DD)

  //                          year day   hour min  sec  millisec
  if(Date.now() - birthDate < 16 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
    console.log("below 16");
  } else {
    console.log("above 16");
  }
}

document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  hasDateCheck();
});
```

```html
<input name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth" type="date" required/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" id="formSubmit">
```

You might run into issues because of leap years (for each leap year, +/- 1 day inaccuracy). You may ignore this problem (few days usually don't cause problems), implement a more complex checking behavior, or reduce the inaccuracy by adding 4 days to the date (there are approximately `16 / 4 = 4` leap years in a 16-year range):

```js
function hasDateCheck() {
  const [YYYY, MM, DD] = document.querySelector("#dateOfBirth").value.split("-");
  const birthDate = new Date(+YYYY, +MM - 1, +DD)

  //                           year day        hour min  sec  millisec
  if(Date.now() - birthDate < (16 * 365 + 4) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
    console.log("below 16");
  } else {
    console.log("above 16");
  }
}

document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  hasDateCheck();
});
```

```html
<input name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth" type="date" required/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" id="formSubmit">
```