# How to check that the user has selected 3 years before date in the textbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to coding I have confused about the concept of Dates in JavaScript. **I need to validate that the user has selected 3 years before's date in the textbox***, but my codes through some errors.* ***Check The Following Code:***

```js
<script>
      function run() {
        var dt =document.getElementById("dt").value; //Value of selected date
        var ndt = new Date(); //Current Date
        var diff = ndt.getTime()-dt.getTime();
        var milliseconds =  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        var result = diff/milliseconds;

        if (result > 1095) {
          alert("Correct");
        } else {
          alert("Wrong")
        };
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: Can you setup a working JSFiddle?

Comment: Yes https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=UzNwBmmLK1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations should be something along the lines:

```js
if (diff > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 3)
```

This is because: 1000ms (is 1 second) * 60 (equals 1 minute) * 60 (equals 1 hour) * 24 (equals one day) * 365 (equals 1 year, roughly) * 3 (equals 3 years).

Surely that's pretty prone to errors! Leap-years are not taken to account, and many more.

I'd suggest you also check this one if you decide to go on a more-stable path: [How can I calculate the number of years between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-between-two-dates)

Comment: I think my code is wrong when I am subtracting ndt from dt because ndt is a date and dt is a string. Can you please solve this issue?

Comment: It really depends on the format of the value. If it's some of the regular ones, you can always do `new Date(dt)` so that it's a Date now. But if it's just an input field, then you've got a problem as people might enter any kind of format. If so - then you should check some date library.

Comment: Thank You, you are right but the only last confusion that what is the default syntax of date is?

Comment: There's no single default, there are many ways to do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date